# Correct way to access pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pvlib

I'm trying to access/create a list of module names from the CEC database accessed by pvlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import pvlib as pv

cecmod = pv.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('CECMod')
```

I want to search the list of module names:

```
matching = [s for s in dir(cecmod) if "Trina" in s]
```

The `dir(cecmod)` part bothers me. I've stumbled on this way of getting the list of dataframe column headings (keys?) but I feel like `dir` isn't meant to be used this way. Why does `dir(pandas.DataFrame)` return this list of column headings instead of a ? Is this the way dataframes are meant to be used? Is there a better way to access these headings/keys?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What is `matching` and what should it contain?

Comment: For those of us who know no `pvlib`, what is the type, structure, and typical value of  `cecmod`? Why would it have a list of module names? As a side note, the list of dataframe `df` column names is in `df.columns` and the row names are in `df.index`.

Comment: cecmod is a pandas dataframe. I'm not sure I can properly explain dataframes, I'm quite confused about them myself. They're a container for objects (pandas series) an seem to be something like a 2d numpy array where each row and column has a title. retrieve_sam() accesses the internet and returns a dataframe which contains thousands of entries each with it's own title. I want a list of those titles in matching. I'm confused because the behaviour of the dataframe returned from pvlib doesn't seem to match the behaviour as described in pandas tutorials.

Comment: `cecmod` is a DataFrame. It is a pandas DataFrame; not a `pvlib DataFrame` (I don't know if something like that even exists). You probably made a mistake somewhere. It acts like every other pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is really bad design. `dir(..)` is meant to list *all* attributes of an object. Although that is not always possible since some objects generate attributes on the fly.

It is also a bad idea to check with `if "Trina" in s`, since it could eventually happen that the search string is in an attribute.

A way to obtain the list of columns is simply use `cecmode.columns`. Which is an `Index(..)` object, like:

```
>>> cecmod.columns
Index(['BEoptCA_Default_Module', 'Example_Module', '1Soltech_1STH_215_P',
       '1Soltech_1STH_220_P', '1Soltech_1STH_225_P', '1Soltech_1STH_230_P',
       '1Soltech_1STH_235_WH', '1Soltech_1STH_240_WH', '1Soltech_1STH_245_WH',
       '1Soltech_1STH_FRL_4H_245_M60_BLK',
       ...
       'Zytech_Solar_ZT275P', 'Zytech_Solar_ZT280P', 'Zytech_Solar_ZT285P',
       'Zytech_Solar_ZT290P', 'Zytech_Solar_ZT295P', 'Zytech_Solar_ZT300P',
       'Zytech_Solar_ZT305P', 'Zytech_Solar_ZT310P', 'Zytech_Solar_ZT315P',
       'Zytech_Solar_ZT320P'],
      dtype='object', length=13953)
```

It is iterable, and then we iterate over the column names:

```
matching = [col for col in cecmod.columns if "Trina" in col]
```

which will yield:

```
>>> [col for col in cecmod.columns if "Trina" in col]
['Trina_Solar_TSM_165DA01', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_170D', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_170DA01', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_170DA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_170PA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_175D', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_175DA01', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_175DA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_175PA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_180D', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_180DA01', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_180DA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_180PA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_185DA01', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_185DA01A', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_185DA01A_05', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_185DA01A_08', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_185DA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_185PA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_190DA01A', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_190DA01A_05', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_190DA01A_08', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_190DA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_190PA03', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_195DA01A', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_195DA01A_05', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_195DA01A_08', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_200DA01A', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_200DA01A_05', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_200DA01A_08', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_205DA01A', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_205DA01A_05', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_205DA01A_08', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_220DA05', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_220PA05', 'Trina_Solar_TSM_220PA05_05', ...
```

(output is cut off).

We can also perform faster matching with `.str.contains('Trina')` like @DYZ says:

```
list(cecmod.columns[cecmod.columns.str.contains('Trina')])
```

Here we let the library do the search work, which will usually outperform Python loops.

Alternatively, use `str.startswith`, assuming the search string resides at the start of your column names:

```
list(cecmod.columns[cecmod.columns.str.startswith('Trina')])
```

If you want the dataframe *columns*, and not just the column names, use `df.filter`:

```
df.filter(like='Trina')
```

Comment: Python loops can be avoided altogether with `matching=df.columns[df.columns.str.find('Trina')!=-1]`.

Comment: Thank you. I knew dir wasn't the way to go but as I said above the pvlib dataframes don't seem to behave like the dataframes described in pandas tutorials.

Comment: Edited your answer a bit, if that's okay. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: @GlenS pvlib creates pandas dataframes from csv files. There is no such thing as a "pvlib dataframe".

Comment: Note that the CEC modules DataFrame created by pvlib transposes rows and columns from the original csv file.  Searching the module data seems easier to me after I transpose the DataFrame back to having module names in the row index and parameter names in the column index.`cecmod = cecmod.T`